# CASL behavior if subject has no rules

Tags: javascript, permissions, rules, subject, casl

When not providing any rule for a given subject in [CASL](https://casl.js.org) checking an ability for this subject always returns false.

E.g.

```js
import { Ability } from '@casl/ability';

const ability = new Ability({
  action: "read", subject: "FirstSubject",
  // no rule for SecondSubject
});

ability.can("read", "FirstSubject");    // true
ability.can("write", "FirstSubject");   // false

ability.can("read", "SecondSubject");   // false  <-- These two lines should
ability.can("write", "SecondSubject");  // false  <-- return `true`
```

Is it possible to change this behavior in a way that the ability returns `true` for subjects that do not have any rules?

In my use case I have a very large amount of subjects and new ones can be added dynamically.
It would be difficult to always having to add `{ action: "manage", subject: "NewSubject"}` whenever a new subject is added.
I would rather like to only add rules for subjects where something is actually restricted.

Answer (score 0):

According to a chat with the author of CASL it is not possible to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to do that:

```
import {Ability} from '@casl/ability';

class AppAbility extends Ability {
  relevantRuleFor (action, subject, field, allowNotDefinedRule) {
    const rule = super.relevantRuleFor(action, subject, field);

    if (!rule && allowNotDefinedRule) {
      return {inverted: false};
    }

    return rule;
  }
}

export const ability = new AppAbility([]);
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
ability.can('read', 'Post', undefined, true);
```

Pls note, that you  componont will not work correct because in the sorces it has this code that has private modificator:

```
private _canRender () {
  const props = this.props;
  const subject = props.of || props.a || props.an || props.this || props.on;
  const can = props.not ? 'cannot' : 'can';

  return props.ability[can](props.I || props.do, subject, props.field);
}
```

In that case you need to create your own component.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```js
import { defineAbility } from '@casl/ability'

const ability = defineAbility((can, cannot) => {
    can(['read','write'],'all')
    cannot('write', 'FirstSubject')
    })

console.log( ability.can("read", "FirstSubject"))   // true
console.log(ability.can("write", "FirstSubject"))   // false
console.log(ability.can("read", "SecondSubject"))   // true  
console.log(ability.can("write", "SecondSubject"))  // true
```